# Drag and drop using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, html

I am working on HTML5 & I am a newbie in it.

I am working on a program which does the following :

1. I want to drag & drop files on a button.
2. User will be able to see all drag dropped files.
3. There needs to be a button to upload files.
4. After uploading, a progress bar should pop up on which there will be cancel upload & skip (if dont want to upload specific file) button.

Kindly let me know how can I do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should get you started. http://playground.html5rocks.com/#drag_and_drop

Comment: -1 - I down voted, because this is something that could clearly found with some looking...

Comment: Try [Google](http://www.google.nl/#q=html5+file+upload+drag+drop+button+progress)

Answer (score 4):

if you know a little jQuery you can use jQuery UI droppable/dragable : http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: User want to do it using HTML5...why to import jquery if the same can be done using HTML5...

Comment: he said he's using HTML5, he never said he wanted it accomplished using html5 but fair enough. Just providing an alternative option...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) are pretty simple examples for everything you asked : files from input tag, files from drag&drop, printing files names and showing a progress bar. I enjoy that website that makes it easy with the 'new' html5 features.